# How to find the BSP sections in the Linux source code?

Tags: linux, kernel

I would like to know how can i search for the BSP(Board Specific Packages) sections in the Linux Source code?

All comments are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A board support package may have pieces spread out in the kernel, but the typical parts are in `arch/`, and if your board requires drivers that aren't already part of the kernel, there may be some pieces in `drivers/`.

Each `arch/` is set up a bit differently. Arm is an interesting one: look in `arch/arm/`, you'll see several cpu types and platforms there. If you look inside a cpu type, like `arch/arm/mach-at91/`, you'll see lots of files for the various specific cpus as well as `board-*.c` files, where board-specific peripherals are set up.